# Find the perpendicular vector for this given space.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

$Q)$ Let $W = \langle w_1, w_2, w_3 \rangle (\subset \mathbb{R^4})$

(Here the $w_1 = (1,0,1,-3), w_2=(-1,2,0,0)$, $w_3=(1,-8,2,9)$  )

Find the $v =(a,b,c,2) \in W^{\bot}$

The answer is at the bottom of this post.

---

My trial) Since $W^{\bot} \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^4$, $dim(W^{\bot}) = 1$

Hence $\langle v,w_i \rangle = 0$ for $i= \{1,2,3\}$

Therefore only solving the below equation, we can get the value of the $(a,b,c)$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}a+c-6=0 \\ -a+2b=0 \\ a-8b+2c+18=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

But the answer was $(a,b,c) = (6,3,0)$

So, Which the point do I have mistake in my trial?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve that system of equations for $a, b, $ and $c$?

Comment: Solving the system you get precisely (6,3,0)

Comment: @HritRoy, Yes.. I just had a error in my computation. I have nothing to say though you downvote my question. :(

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I didn't downvote your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track.

Your system is equivalent to $c=6-a$, $a=2b$, and $a-8b+2c+18=0$,

which means $a-4a+12-2a+18=0$, which means $-5a+30=0$ or $a=6$.

Can you now solve for $b$ and $c$  ?

Comment: I did silly things. Yes my process was right. only My mistake was computation of that system.